# React Native program returns "Unable to resolve "srcscreensComponentsScreenListScreen" from "App.js"

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, json, error-handling

I have a JavaScript error. This is my code it seems that I get an error in  the react native. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
     import HomeScreen from './src/screens/HomeScreen';
     import ComponentsScreen from 
       './src/screens/ComponentsScreen/componentsscreen';
     import ListScreen from './src/screen/ComponentsScreen/ListScreen';
         const navigator = createStackNavigator(
         {
          Home: HomeScreen,
         Components: ComponentsScreen,
         List:ListScreen
           },
            {
           initialRouteName: 'List',
           defaultNavigationOptions: {
             title: 'App',
             },
          }
        };
```

Error:

> 14:16
> Unable to resolve "srcscreensComponentsScreenListScreen" from "App.js"

Answer (score 0):

I have created a minimal sample and I can import ListScreen just fine. https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-sky-q31c5?file=/src/App.js. Please check how you exported it.

Comment: Hi Viet. Could you add a sample of your code or a description of your debugging technique in your answer? This is essentially a link-only answer at present and is thus at risk of community deletion. Although links to code runners and sandboxes are welcome, they are liable to breakage, and thus we tend not to let them stand on their own. If you wish, you can delete your answer and post the link as a comment.